# Perform a calculation using columns located in tables linked by successive relationships

Tags: powerbi, dax, relationship, powerbi-desktop

## Model Overview

**dSystème** : Existence of a set of systems on which employees are working
**fCompétencePersonne** : Employee competence has been evaluated (NivCompétence) for each system
**fIplanning** : An export of the schedule provides a list of activities that employees are working on
**dTypeActivité** : Activities are characterized by a Presence Factor, which is a number between 0 and 1 (FacteurPrésence)

[image: Model View]

[image: Tables Sample]

## Objective

Display a table showing, for each system, the sum of [skills weighted by the presence factor].

Compared to what appears in the image below, I would like to display the product of the presence factors by the sum of skills.
[image: Matrix with almost what I want]

In this image, the measure does SUM(0 + 0.5 + 1) * SUM(SkillLevel). I get 24, whereas I want to have 16.
[image: Trying to display what I want with a measure]

## Questions

How can I achieve the desired visualization?
Bonus question : Are there improvements to be made to the model? In particular, I am not sure if using bidirectional relationships is a good thing or not.

## What I tried so far

I have tried using various combinations of SUMX, RELATED, RELATEDTABLE, but to no avail.
I have not explored creating columns in the tables.

I assume that in SQL, an appropriate query would be:

```
select   
    sum(Nivcompetence * FacteurPrésence)  
from  
    fIplanning   
    natural join dTypeActivité  
    natural join dPersonne  
    natural join fCompétencePersonne  
    natural join dSystème  
group by SystèmeID
```